# laravel mix build successfully but vue.js new component not working or any changes not appearing

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

First time i am using vue.js in my laravel app. every-time message appear that laravel mix build successfully but my vie.js comment changes not displaying.

```
require('./bootstrap');
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));
Vue.component('my-vuetable', require('./components/MyVuetable.vue'));

const app = new Vue({

el: '#app'

});
```

i forget to run any important command ?

view:

```
 <div class="content">
        <div class="title m-b-md">
            Laravel
        </div>
        <div id="app">

          <example></example>
        </div>
 </div>
```

**Component**

```html
<template>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h1>Example Component</h1>
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body"> I'm an example component 5 </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
<script> 
    export default { 
        mounted() { 
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried? `app.js` or any component?

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham i am just try to change in default example.vue file

Comment: Add above code and more explanation in your question

Comment: where are you calling `<my-vuetable>`

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham now i am not using it, because vue.js not loading at all. i trued with   <my-vuetable></my-vuetable>

after that i just try to edit default example.vue not working :(

Comment: post your component and view code where are you are using this component

Comment: It seems everything is correct. Did you included `public/app.js`? what commands did you executed? Is there any console log when you visit the page?

Answer (score 1):

in bootstrap.js look for 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken, and comment it out

Comment: Thank you so much dude.. It works great. By the way can you tell me about this TOKEN?